# Remove duplicates from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a python script which parses an xml file and then gives me the required information. My output looks like this, and is 100% correct:

```
output = ['77:275,77:424,77:425,77:426,77:427,77:412,77:413,77:414,77:412,77:413,77:414,77:412,77:413,77:414,77:412,77:413,77:414,77:431,77:432,77:433,77:435,77:467,77:470,77:471,77:484,77:485,77:475,77:476,77:437,77:438,77:439,77:440,77:442,77:443,77:444,77:445,77:446,77:447,77:449,77:450,77:451,77:454,77:455,77:456,77:305,77:309,77:496,77:497,77:500,77:504,77:506,77:507,77:508,77:513,77:515,77:514,77:517,77:518,77:519,77:521,77:522,77:523,77:403,77:406,77:404,77:405,77:403,77:406,77:404,77:405,77:526,77:496,77:497,77:500,77:504,77:506,77:507,77:508,77:513,77:515,77:514,77:517,77:518,77:519,77:521,77:522,77:523,77:403,77:406,77:404,77:405,77:403,77:406,77:404,77:405,77:526,77:317,77:321,77:346,77:349,77:350,77:351,77:496,77:497,77:500,77:504,77:506,77:507,77:508,77:513,77:515,77:514,77:517,77:518,77:519,77:521,77:522,77:523,77:403,77:406,77:404,77:405,77:403,77:406,77:404,77:405,77:526,77:496,77:497,77:500,77:504,77:506,77:507,77:508,77:513,77:515,77:514,77:517,77:518,77:519,77:521,77:522,77:523,77:403,77:406,77:404,77:405,77:403,77:406,77:404,77:405,77:526,77:362,77:367,77:369,77:374,77:370,77:372,77:373,77:387,77:388,77:389,77:392,77:393,77:394,77:328,77:283,77:284,77:285,77:288,77:289,77:290,77:292,']
```

It is all fine, but I want to remove the duplicate elements in an element, like in the case above. I tried using the OrderedDict package or just simple list(set(output)), but obvoiusly they both didn't work. Does anyone have a tip for me on how to solve this problem.

Comment: You have a list with just **one** element, a long string. If you expected that to be treated as separate elements, you'll need to split that string, after which your techniques (`OrderedDict` or `set`) will work just fine.

Comment: Try this print list(set(output[0].split(',')))

Comment: It must be exactly the same as mine, but without the dupliate. @MartijnPieters that is what I'm doing at the moment, just adding "".join().

Answer (score 4):

You have *one element* in a list. If you expected it to be treated as separate elements, you need to explicitly split it.

You could split the string on the `','` comma character into a list with `str.split()`:

```
separate_elements = output[0].split(',')
```

after which you can use `set()` (unordered) or `OrderedDict` (maintaining order) and re-join the string if you still need just the one string object:

```
','.join(set(separate_elements))
```

You can put that back into a list with just one element, but there is little point if all you ever handle is that one string.